# I cannot seem to enable plugins for RabbitMQ, after going to /usr/local/sbin

Tags: rabbitmq

I use the command `sh rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_shovel rabbitmq_shovel_management`, while I am in the directory `/usr/local/sbin`.

It is giving me an error saying `rabbitmq-plugins: line 30: rabbitmq-plugins/rabbitmq-env: Not a directory`. I looked at the shell script, and there really doesn't seem to be anything I can do. Is this a bug?

I am using Mac OS X. Why is it giving me this error? Shouldn't I be able to enable these plugins? Thank you!

Comment: How did you install RabbitMQ?

Comment: I used "brew install rabbitmq". Is there another way that avoids this problem?

Comment: I only run RabbitMQ using the `generic-unix` package on OS X. I'm assuming you're in a development environment - `generic-unix` works very well for that.